# Superpowered SDK popping sounds with multiple players

Tags: android, audio, sdk, superpowered

I get popping sounds when simultaneously playing multiple SuperpoweredAudioPlayers. When one SuperpoweredAudioPlayer is playing a moderately loud sound, a popping sound gets made when I call play() on a second SuperpoweredAudioPlayer, even if there is initial silence in the second player and the process() volume is set to 0. I can't have pops in the output since I'm making a music production app. The output also needs to be generated in real time. Am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround? Would it be fixed by having the players in separate threads?

Answer (score 0):

Separate threads are definitely not the solution, as all your audio processing should happen on the same thread. Two audio players are very low with CPU, you don't have a processing problem.

Perhaps you forgot to handle the return value of the process() function. If it's false, then it means silence, and the buffer is not updated (zeroed) at all.

Comment: This is how I handle process(): silence = true; (...) if (players[i]->process(stereoBuffer, !silence, numberOfSamples, vmul * headroom, masterBpm, msElapsedSinceLastBeat)) silence = false; (...) return silence;  Have a look at the C++ file if you want to reproduce the pops: https://codepaste.net/5nxiom It's just an edited CrossExample

Comment: Never call time in an audio processing callback, as it may block.

Comment: Calculate "time" with the number of samples. Every call to the audio processing callback represents the same time!

Comment: It wasn't the time() calls, but I seem to have fixed it. Instead of calling play() to play a sound and pause() to stop it, I just modulate the volume multiplier. After calling play() on each player (initially causing popping), simply changing the volume and using seek() as the play method eliminates the pops. It seems Superpowered's play() and/or stop() blocks the audio processing and so their work should be moved to a separate thread. Anyway, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Play and stop doesn't block. Superpowered is prepared to be called from any thread. What you heard as popping was ramping from silence to volume and volume to silence, called rapidly.

Comment: Not true. When a sound was playing on a separate player and I play()ed a silent sound, the pop still occurred so there was no difference in volume. Superpowered must have been blocking.

Comment: I'm the developer of Superpowered. Those methods don't block, they are just a few lines of code putting a message into a lockless message queue.

Comment: You should be able to figure out what blocks the playback then by reproducing the issue. Code without pops: https://codepaste.net/naospv https://codepaste.net/w9ddd5 Good luck!

Comment: Good luck making me reviewing code for free. :-) As i mentioned earlier, don't depend on time(), as every call in the audio processing callback represents the same time. Follow time by the number of samples.

Comment: If you looked at the fixed code, you would have seen that the working callback still contains the time() call. Have some negative reputation for your SDK with that attitude toward bug reports... it's free! :)

Comment: This is not a bug report for Superpowered, but for your own custom code. We do provide custom code review services, but not for free, sorry. We receive too many requests.

Comment: I'm not asking for a code review; I'm saying your software is buggy and I gave you proof that it isn't my code by leaving the process() callback unchanged (which you stated was the issue). The only thing left for you to do here is fix the bug. I hope you saved my example code like a responsible developer. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thousands of apps are using "my code", many of them with a similar scenario (heavy looping with mixing), such as Soundcamp by Samsung or Remixlive by MixVibes. They don't have this issue.